# dask read_csv is fast but dataframe operation is slow

Tags: dask, dask-dataframe

I am trying to improve speed of read_csv() then later dataframe using pandas 2. I tried dask today and read_csv() is indeed really fast. But dataframe operation is slow. why is that? how to improve the speed of dataframe oepration after using dask?

Thanks

Here is the speed comparison between pandas 2 and dask

1. read_csv() using pandas 2: 172 seconds

```
timer_start=timeit.default_timer()
df_pyarrow=pd.read_csv('input\\'+filename,parse_dates=True,sep='\t',engine='pyarrow')  
timer_end=timeit.default_timer()

timer_minutes=(timer_end-timer_start)/60
timer_seconds=(timer_end-timer_start)

print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_seconds:.1f} seconds')
print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_minutes:.2f} minutes')

Time took to Finish reading file is 172.2 seconds
Time took to Finish reading file is 2.87 minutes
```

2. read_csv() using dask, it only takes 4 seconds

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
timer_start=timeit.default_timer()
ddf=dd.read_csv('input\\'+filename,parse_dates=True,sep='\t',sample=1000000)  
# ddf=dd.read_csv('input\\'+filename,parse_dates=True,sep='\t')  
timer_end=timeit.default_timer()

timer_minutes=(timer_end-timer_start)/60
timer_seconds=(timer_end-timer_start)

print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_seconds:.1f} seconds')
print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_minutes:.2f} minutes')
Time took to Finish reading file is 4.1 seconds
Time took to Finish reading file is 0.07 minute
```

Now after getting dataframe, I just addded a new column, using pandas 2 it is almost 0 seconds, however using dask it will take much longer, here is comparison

```
timer_start=timeit.default_timer()
df_pyarrow['new_col']=0
timer_end=timeit.default_timer()
timer_minutes=(timer_end-timer_start)/60
timer_seconds=(timer_end-timer_start)
print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_seconds:.1f} seconds')
print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_minutes:.2f} minutes')

Time took to Finish reading file is 0.0 seconds
Time took to Finish reading file is 0.00 minutes
```

Now for dask's dataframe, it takes 6 seconds to add a new column which is even slower than read_csv(), why is that? How to improve the speed of dataframe operation when using dask()? Thanks

```
timer_start=timeit.default_timer()
ddf['new_col']=0
timer_end=timeit.default_timer()
timer_minutes=(timer_end-timer_start)/60
timer_seconds=(timer_end-timer_start)
print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_seconds:.1f} seconds')
print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_minutes:.2f} minutes')

Time took to Finish reading file is 6.7 seconds
Time took to Finish reading file is 0.11 minutes
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you've missed an important detail as to how dask works.

This doens't read a single CSV:

```py
ddf = dd.read_csv('input\\'+filename,parse_dates=True,sep='\t',sample=1000000)
```

What it does instead is build a task graph.

You can add items to this task graph by continuing to tack on other operations. e.g., `.groupby`, `.join` etc.

Generally speaking, none of the tasks you add will be executed until you call

```py
df_in_memory = ddf.compute()
```

However, some operations have implicit calls to compute. It appears that

```py
ddf['new_col'] = 0
```

...is one of them.

To compare apples to apples, time all of your operations. By that I'm

```py
timer_start=timeit.default_timer()
df_pyarrow = ( 
    pd.read_csv('input\\'+filename,parse_dates=True,sep='\t',engine='pyarrow')
        .assign(newcol=0)
)  
timer_end=timeit.default_timer()
timer_minutes=(timer_end-timer_start)/60
timer_seconds=(timer_end-timer_start)

print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_seconds:.1f} seconds')
print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_minutes:.2f} minutes')
```

vs

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

timer_start=timeit.default_timer()
ddf = (
    dd.read_csv('input\\'+filename,parse_dates=True,sep='\t',sample=1000000)  
      .assign(newcol=0)
).compute()
timer_end=timeit.default_timer()

timer_minutes=(timer_end-timer_start)/60
timer_seconds=(timer_end-timer_start)

print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_seconds:.1f} seconds')
print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_minutes:.2f} minutes')
```

Note that dask's task graph-based approach does require a bit of overhead. If your production data fit in memory, I wouldn't expect much of a performance gain.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I tried your code for apply to apply comparison. using pandas 2, it takes 349.2 seconds, while using dask, it takes 585.6 seconds. So pandas 2 is much faster than dask.

Comment: @roudan in some cases yes. When you have 3 TB of data, not so much.

Comment: No Paul I only have 300 MB data.